# Как html код вставить в php

Tags: php, html, циклы, redbeanphp

У меня есть личный блог, в котором можно создавать посты, но не много остановился на этом. У меня есть php код который  пробегает по базе данных и вытягивает от туда текст. Мне теперь нужно как-то написать цикл, чтобы создавался определенный html код когда запись есть.

То есть в базе данных у меня есть 2 поста.PHP код циклом пробегает и вставляет как то html код, где в нем вставляется php код с текстом. Как можно реализовать?

```
    <?php
$ids = [9,10,11];
$stats = R::loadAll('book', $ids);
foreach ($stat as $stat){
  echo $stat->text;
}

?>
<div class="posts">

  <div class="post">
                  <div class="post_text">
                      <p><?php
                      echo $text_post;
                      
                      ?></p>
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все довольно просто, вывод `HTML` посредством `php`, осуществляется через функцию `echo`. Для экранирования кавычек используйте `\`.

Если рассматривать ваш пример, то будет примерно вот так:

```
<?php
   function showPost($text_post){
       echo "<div class=\"post\"><div class=\"post_text\"> 
             <p>".$text_post."</p></div></div>";

   }
?>
<div class="posts">

  
<?php
    $ids = [9,10,11];
    $stats = R::loadAll('book', $ids);
    foreach ($stat as $stat){
       showPost($stat->text);
    }       
                      
?>
      
</div>
```